# Dispose vs Terminate vs Shutdown in ZContext

Tags: c#, winforms, zeromq

I am confused to see following 3 similar methods available in [Zeromq C# API](http://zeromq.org/bindings:clr).

1. Dispose
2. Terminate
3. Shutdown

The above 3 methods looks similar by name. However I am not sure about their proper meaning.

Basically, in the provided examples such as [Weather update server](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:wuserver), the dispose functionality is done automatically by C# because of keyword `using`. However, in my code, I want to dispose the `ZContext` object manually.  See below the code snippet:

```
public partial class DataPublisherForm : Form
{
    private ZContext zmqContext;
    private ZSocket sensorDataPublisher;

    public DataPublisherForm()
    {
        mySensor = new Sensor();
        mySensor.DataArrived += OnDataArrived;
        zmqContext = new ZContext();
        sensorDataPublisher = new ZSocket(zmqContext, ZSocketType.PUB);
        sensorDataPublisher.SetOption(ZSocketOption.CONFLATE, 1);
        sensorDataPublisher.Bind("tcp://*:10000");
    }

    private void OnDataArrived(object sender, DataArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] sensorData = e.getSenorData();
        sensorDataPublisher.Send(new ZFrame(sensorData));
    }

    private void DataPublisherForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        zmqContext.Shutdown();
        if (sensorDataPublisher != null)
        {
            sensorDataPublisher.Close();
            sensorDataPublisher.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Following are my observations:

1. `Dispose`: When I use `Dispose` method, the application hangs (doesn't respond)
2. `Shutdown`: When I use `Shutdown` method, the application closes smoothly.

Below are my queries:

1. What is the proper way to dispose `ZContext` and `ZSocket` objects?
2. What is the difference among `Dispose`, `Terminate` and `Shutdown` methods?

Comment: Well, you can look at the source code to see what each method is actually doing... I would imaging a reasonable scenario would be that would be terminate, shutdown and then dispose, but that's just my logic, I don't know what's under the hood there and don't really have the time to check.

Comment: @ZoharPeled FYI: The `.Shutdown()` method per-se does not help ( as underlying API defines, that there is still a user's responsibility to later call a `.Terminate()` method ). The `.Dispose()` method starts with a call to `GC.SuppressFinalize( this )` and next internally calls `.Terminate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short version:

Well, there are certain magics under the hood of the ZeroMQ `zmqContext()` instance, which may well turn things into havoc.

`.Terminate()` method is a mandatory API-call
`.Shutdown()` method wraps an optional-only API-call, with a must to call the mandatory API-call
`.Dispose()` method does `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` first and calls `.Terminate()`

---

### Best practices:

Be nice to resources. Better manage them explicitly and with a due care.
Be cautions on closing the things, that worked. Can hang the whole circus by not doing things right.

```
public partial class DataPublisherForm : Form
{
    private ZContext zmqContext;                 // a Context() class-instance
    private ZSocket sensorDataPublisher;         // a Socket()  class-instance
 // -------------------------------------------- // this.VERSION details
    private int     majorVerNUM,
                    minorVerNUM,
                    patchVerNUM;

    private string libzmqVerSTR;
 // -------------------------------------------- //
    public DataPublisherForm()                   // CONSTRUCTOR:
    {
        zmqContext = new ZContext();
        zmq.zmq_version( this.majorVerNUM,       // Ref. a trailer note:
                         this.minorVerNUM,
                         this.patchVerNUM
                         );
        this.libzmqVerSTR = string.Format( "libzmq DLL is version {0}",
                                            zmq.LibraryVersion()
                                            );

        mySensor = new Sensor();
        mySensor.DataArrived += OnDataArrived;

        sensorDataPublisher = new ZSocket(zmqContext, ZSocketType.PUB);
        sensorDataPublisher.SetOption(ZSocketOption.CONFLATE, 1);
        sensorDataPublisher.Bind("tcp://*:10000");
    }

    private void OnDataArrived(object sender, DataArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] sensorData = e.getSenorData();
        sensorDataPublisher.Send(new ZFrame(sensorData));
    }

    private void DataPublisherForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sensorDataPublisher != null)
        {   sensorDataPublisher.SetOption( ZSocketOption.LINGER, 0 );
            sensorDataPublisher.Close();
            sensorDataPublisher.Dispose();
        }
     // -------------------------<NEVER BEFORE SAFE DISMANTLING ALL SOCKETS>---
        zmqContext.Shutdown();                   // optional  API-call
        zmqContext.Terminate();                  // mandatory API-call
    }
 // -------------------------------------------- // VERSION CONTROL METHODS
    public  string  getDllVersionSTRING()        // a DLL version
    {   return this.libzmqVerSTR;
    }

    public  int getVersionMAJOR()                // a version() responder
    {   
        return this.majorVerNUM;
    }

    public  int getVersionMINOR()                // a version() responder
    {   
        return this.minorVerNUM;
    }

    public  int getVersionPATCH()                // a version() responder
    {   
        return this.patchVerNUM;
    }

}
```

A few version-control methods were just sketched in principle, not finalised in detail, the less tested. The rationale for using a similar concept is in the fact that one cannot ensure ( enforce ) a realistic, distributed ecosystem, where only homogeneous API-versions are granted.

Thus in many operational cases, the API-versions need not match and ZeroMQ has ( besides its own version evolution ) different behaviour requirements ( performance-wise, memory-wise, {local|non-local}-processing-wise ) and having methods to locally detect which API-version or DLL-version is actually used / linked against, is worth having them ( debugging report being the Case#1, not to mention other, API-specific decisions taken on-the-fly ).

An ability to ask a class-method to answer these actual version details could literally save one's hair in troubles during a bug-hunt or after a new version release there comes a review of all related engineering changes and tracking new decision points introduced by all the new features / changed modus operandi.